# Shell Script (in Crontab) : Saving Memory print into text file always gives blank

Tags: shell-script, cron, memory

In my CentOS, i'm trying to print the CPU USAGE and FREE MEMORY output numbers into a text file. But when i typing in the terminal, it is all fine. But when it is executed via the `crontab` the MEMORY output is always blank.

Manually typing in terminal:

```
# echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`, RAM: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)` >> ~/stats.txt
# cat ~/stats.txt
CPU: 3.8, RAM: 1307
```

Same command in Crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * echo CPU: `top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`, RAM: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m)` >> ~/stats.txt
```

Then inside the Text file:

```
# cat ~/stats.txt
CPU: 3.4, RAM: 
CPU: 4.1, RAM: 
CPU: 3.9, RAM:
```

Why is the **RAM** output always blank please?

Comment: Perhaps `cron` is running your command in a shell that doesn't support `<(...)` process substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dash` doesn't understand this kind of bashism:

```
<(free -m)
```

Instead, use:

```
free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}'
```